# Postgres Insert/Update query not working as expected

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert

Here's a simplified version of a query I'm trying to write. It's intended to save a row as a variable `combine`, then `UPDATE` the media_hashtags table if a specific entry exists, else INSERT that entry.

```
    WITH 
      combine AS (
        SELECT * FROM hashtags WHERE hashtag_text='HOPPA'
      )
    UPDATE media_hashtags SET hashtag_id = (SELECT id FROM combine) WHERE user_id = 58 AND media_id=161;
      INSERT INTO media_hashtags (media_id, user_id, hashtag_id)
    SELECT 161, 58, (SELECT id FROM combine)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM media_hashtags
      WHERE (
        user_id = 58 AND
        media_id = 161
      )
    )

    RETURNING *
```

However, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  relation "combine" does not exist
LINE 8:      SELECT 161, 58, (SELECT id FROM combine)
```

Interestingly, If I do a query with only the `UPDATE` or only the `INSERT` commands, then it executes as expected. The error only occurs when I do both at once. Any ideas on what the problem is, and a fix?

Comment: There seems to be two separate queries here (look for the semicolon). It's natural that the second one does not see the `combine` from the first

Comment: That makes sense. I suppose I could re-write the combine, but that would be verbose. Is there a better way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two queries, the first one ends with the `;` after the `UPDATE` statement. The following `INSERT` does not see the CTE any more because it's a new statement.

If you want to run this as a single statement, you need to move the `UPDATE` into it's own CTE:

```
WITH combine AS (
    SELECT id 
    FROM hashtags 
    WHERE hashtag_text='HOPPA'
), changed AS (
  UPDATE media_hashtags 
     SET hashtag_id = (SELECT id FROM combine) 
  WHERE user_id = 58 
    AND media_id=161
)  
INSERT INTO media_hashtags (media_id, user_id, hashtag_id)
SELECT 161, 58, (SELECT id FROM combine)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM media_hashtags
  WHERE (
    user_id = 58 AND
    media_id = 161
  )
)
RETURNING *;
```

---

You should also only select the columns you need in the initial CTE. The fact that the subsequent statements only use a single column from `combine` won't be pushed into the first query so Postgres might not query `hashtags` as efficient as it potentially could.

---

If you are using Postgres 9.5 you can simplify the statement using the  `on conflict` clause for the `insert` statement:

```
INSERT INTO media_hashtags (media_id, user_id, hashtag_id)
SELECT 161, 58, id
FROM hashtags 
WHERE hashtag_text='HOPPA'
ON CONFLICT (media_id, user_id) DO UPDATE 
  SET hashtag_id = excluded.hashtag_id;
```

This requires a unique index on `media_hashtags(media_id, user_id)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Temporary table to store data from hashtags and then insert and update operations.

Here is the way:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_hashtags;
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_hashtags AS
SELECT * FROM hashtags WHERE hashtag_text='HOPPA';

UPDATE media_hashtags 
    SET hashtag_id = (SELECT id FROM temp_hashtags) 
WHERE user_id = 58 AND media_id=161;

INSERT INTO media_hashtags (media_id, user_id, hashtag_id)
SELECT 161, 58, (SELECT id FROM temp_hashtags)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM media_hashtags
        WHERE user_id = 58 AND media_id = 161
        );
```